# Running an executable before index.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, executable

I have written a file that needs to execute before the index.js, since it uses commander to require the user to pass information to the index file. I have it placed in a bin directory, but I'm not sure how to make it run. I can `cd` into the directory and run `node <file_name>` and pass it the values needed, and it runs fine (As I export the index and import it into the file and call it at the end) but is there not a way to add it into the `package.json` to run it with an easier command?

Executable:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const program = require('commander');
const index = require('../src/index.js')

program
 .version('0.0.1')
 .option('-k, --key <key>')
 .option('-s, --secret <secret>')
 .option('-i, --id <id>')
 .parse(process.argv);
 
let key = program.key;
let secret = program.secret;
let publicId = program.id;

index(key, secret, publicId);
```

Comment: Sounds like something solved with a little batch file or shell script that runs your first program and then feeds the output from that into your nodejs program.

Comment: @jfriend00 Btw, this is exactly what package.json `bin` does, it automatically creates a set of shell script and .cmd files on installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Node.js script is supposed to run as executable, it's specified as package.json [`bin` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin):

> To use this, supply a bin field in your package.json which is a map of command name to local file name. On install, npm will symlink that file into prefix/bin for global installs, or ./node_modules/.bin/ for local installs.

It can be located in `src` or elsewhere:

```
{
  ...
  "bin" : { "foo" : "src/bin.js" },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but error out when I try to `npm run` with:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 140 while parsing near '...st": "happiness",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   },
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "bin": {
npm ERR! JSON.parse     "s...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

I've checked the parenthesis and they all line up correctly

Comment: If this was valid JSON, you wouldn't see this error. Consider checking it with https://jsonlint.com/ . Please, update the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem in case you weren't able to resolve it.